# How to create a dynamic file resource from angular service factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is possible to have a dynamic file resource?

This is my factory

```
factory('fileResourcedc', function ($resource) {
    var FileResourcedc = $resource(
                'xml/file.json',{},
                {
                    get:{method:'GET', isArray:false}
                }
            );
    return FileResourcedc;
})
```

And I am calling it from here:

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var successFn = function (result) {
        if (angular.equals(result, [])) {
            deferred.reject("Failed  because empty : " + result.message);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    };
    var failFn = function (result) {
       deferred.reject("Failed dataconfResponse");
    };
    fileResourcedc.get(successFn, failFn);
    return deferred.promise;
```

Note that in my factory, the filename is hard coded:

```
'xml/file.json'
```

What I need is to create a filename parameter and pass it to factory service. Is it possible?

Thaks in advance

Comment: just create a service for the filename (like filename provider ) and inject it in your resource via the factory definition. edit : your resource service if dynamic should be a method rather than an object `fileResource.getResource().get( ... )`

Comment: @mpm Thanks, good Angular way instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
factory('fileResourcedc', function ($resource) {
    var FileResourcedc = $resource(
                'xml/:myFile',
                {},
                {
                    get:{method:'GET', params:{myFile:""}, isArray:false}
                }
            );
    FileResourcedc.prototype.getCatalogue = function (fileName, successCat, failCat) {
        return FileResourcedc.get({myFile:fileName}, successCat, failCat);

    };
    return new FileResourcedc;
})
```

Call:

```
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var successFn = function (result) {
            if (angular.equals(result, {})) {
                deferred.reject("No catalogue");
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }
        };
        var failFn = function (result) {
           deferred.reject("Failed catalogue");
        };
        fileResourcedc.getCatalogue("catalogues.json",successFn, failFn);
        return deferred.promise;
```

Thanks!