# how to create a resource factory with dynamic URL for the resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources

I am using angular in a mobile app. I want to use angular's `$resource` to create resources to get data from my restful server. Also i am using multiple-domain support. Each domain has its own URL which is the base URL for all server queries. To dynamically provide base URL i created a service called `domainService`. I can get the base URL like :

```
var baseURL = domainService.getBaseURL()
```

The problem is when i m creating the resource this method can't be used to change the base URL dynamically. As factory is singleton only one instance is created.

```
    angular.module('resources.announcementResource',[])
    .factory('announcementResource',function(domainService,$resource) {

        var baseURL = domainService.getBaseURL() + '/announcement/:id';

        return new $resource(baseURL , {
                id:'@id'
            });
    });
```

In this case the url doesn't changes. I have also tried the solution from: 
[How to create a dynamic file resource from angular service factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907983/how-to-create-a-dynamic-file-resource-from-angular-service-factory) like this

```
angular.module('resources.announcementResource',[])
.factory('announcementResource',function(domainService,$resource) {
        var announcementResource  = {};

        announcementResource.getResource = function() {
            var baseURL = domainService.getBaseURL() + '/announcement/:id';
            return $resource(baseURL , {
                id:'@id'
            });
        }

        return announcementResource;

    });
```

but the problem in this was i am using same resource to create new announcements as well. So i can't get the new resource object and can't call `$save` on this like this

> `var announcement  = announcementResource.getResource().$save();`

I have also tried some other solution like :

```
 angular.module('resources.announcementResource',[])
    .factory('announcementResource',function(domainService,$resource) {

       return new $resource(getBaseURL() , {
            id:'@id'
        });

function getBaseURL() {
                return domainService.getBaseURL() + '/announcement/:id';
            }
            //return announcementResource;

        });
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As per my understanding you have more then one restful api endpoints and you want to use all in a single application, am i right?

Comment: Something like that ......

Comment: Maybe you can use the solution in this article (did not try it myself): http://tikalk.com/overcoming-angularjs-singleton-service-limitation